# Cesium: dynamically change position of an entity on the basis of positions array

Tags: cesiumjs

I have a JSON of positions (lat,lon,alt) of an entity with 10 seconds periodicity. I need to change the position of an entity dynamicaly, regarding to the clock value.

What I've done: I set a timer, which periodically checks the clock value. Using linear interpolation I calculate the position of the entity and change it.

Is there a better way? If yes, please share examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `SampledPositionsProperty` functionality for this purpose.

```
  function computePositions(arr) {

      var property = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();

      for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      {
        var position= new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees( arr[i].lon, arr[i].lat, arr[i].alt);
        var time=new Date(arr[i].time+" +0000");
        property.addSample(new Cesium.JulianDate.fromDate(time), position);

      }

      return property;
  }
```

Comment: Correct.  You can also use CZML (a JSON-based language) to stream this kind of data from server to client.

Comment: @emackey Thanks! Cesium is very nice, I've already implemented some applications. Now I'm trying to figure out, whether there is a functionality of 'free camera', as in Unity.